# how to put a link on the photo after the photo opens?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hope you don't mind helping me with this code.
 I'm using bootstrap and I have this html:

```
   <div class="gallery">
       <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 gallery-item">
                <a href="#galleryImg1" class="link-gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery">
                    <img src="images/port1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-gallery" alt="Projekti i pare">
                </a>
            </div> <!-- /.col -->

            <div class="col-xs-3 gallery-item">
                <a href="#galleryImg1" class="link-gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery">
                    <img src="images/port2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-gallery" alt="Projekti i dyte">
                </a>
            </div> <!-- /.col -->

            <div class="col-xs-3 gallery-item">
                <a href="#galleryImg1" class="link-gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery">
                    <img src="images/port3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-gallery" alt="Projekti i trete">
                </a>
            </div> <!-- /.col -->

            <div class="col-xs-3 gallery-item">
                <a href="#galleryImg1" class="link-gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery">
                    <img src="images/port4.jpg" class="img-responsive img-gallery" alt="Projekti i katert">
                </a>
            </div> <!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-xs-3 gallery-item">
                <a href="#galleryImg1" class="link-gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery">
                    <img src="images/port4.jpg" class="img-responsive img-gallery" alt="Projekti i peste">
                </a>
            </div> <!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-xs-3 gallery-item">
                <a href="#galleryImg1" class="link-gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery">
                    <img src="images/port4.jpg" class="img-responsive img-gallery" alt="Projekti i gjashte">
                </a>
            </div> <!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-xs-3 gallery-item">
                <a href="#galleryImg1" class="link-gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery">
                    <img src="images/port4.jpg" class="img-responsive img-gallery" alt="Projekti i shtate">
                </a>
                   </div> <!-- /.col -->
              </div> <!--/.row  -->
            </div> <!-- /.container -->
        </div> <!-- /.gallery -->

       <div class="modal fade" id="modalGallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalGalleryLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalGalleryLabel">Gallery</h4>
            </div> <!-- /.modal-header -->

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="carouselGallery" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                    </div> <!-- /.carousel-inner -->
                </div> <!-- /.carousel -->
            </div> <!-- /.modal-body -->

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <ul class="pagination">
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- /.modal-footer -->
        </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div> <!-- /.modal -->
```

This is my css:

```
   .gallery{
margin-top: 100px;
     }
  .gallery-item{
   margin-bottom: 30px;
     }
    .modal-footer{
     text-align: center;
   }
    .pagination{
    margin: 0;
    }
```

And my Javacsript

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.link-gallery').click(function(){
    var galleryId = $(this).attr('data-target');
    var currentLinkIndex = $(this).index('a[data-target="'+ galleryId +'"]');

    createGallery(galleryId, currentLinkIndex);
    createPagination(galleryId, currentLinkIndex);

    $(galleryId).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (){
        destroyGallry(galleryId);
        destroyPagination(galleryId);
    });

    $(galleryId +' .carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (){
        var currentSlide = $(galleryId +' .carousel .item.active');
        var currentSlideIndex = currentSlide.index(galleryId +' .carousel .item');

        setTitle(galleryId, currentSlideIndex);
        setPagination(++currentSlideIndex, true);
    })
});

function createGallery(galleryId, currentSlideIndex){
    var galleryBox = $(galleryId + ' .carousel-inner');

    $('a[data-target="'+ galleryId +'"]').each(function(){
        var img = $(this).html();
        var galleryItem = $('<div class="item">'+ img +'</div>');

        galleryItem.appendTo(galleryBox);
    });

    galleryBox.children('.item').eq(currentSlideIndex).addClass('active');
    setTitle(galleryId, currentSlideIndex);
}

function destroyGallry(galleryId){
    $(galleryId + ' .carousel-inner').html("");
}

function createPagination(galleryId, currentSlideIndex){
    var pagination = $(galleryId + ' .pagination');
    var carouselId = $(galleryId).find('.carousel').attr('id');
    var prevLink = $('<li><a href="#'+ carouselId +'" data-slide="prev">«</a></li>');
    var nextLink = $('<li><a href="#'+ carouselId +'" data-slide="next">»</a></li>');

    prevLink.appendTo(pagination);
    nextLink.appendTo(pagination);

    $('a[data-target="'+ galleryId +'"]').each(function(){
        var linkIndex = $(this).index('a[data-target="'+ galleryId +'"]');
        var paginationLink = $('<li><a data-target="#carouselGallery" data-slide-to="'+ linkIndex +'">'+ (linkIndex+1) +'</a></li>');

        paginationLink.insertBefore('.pagination li:last-child');
    });

    setPagination(++currentSlideIndex);
}

function setPagination(currentSlideIndex, reset = false){
    if (reset){
        $('.pagination li').removeClass('active');
    }

    $('.pagination li').eq(currentSlideIndex).addClass('active');
}

function destroyPagination(galleryId){
    $(galleryId + ' .pagination').html("");
}

function setTitle(galleryId, currentSlideIndex){
    var imgAlt = $(galleryId + ' .item').eq(currentSlideIndex).find('img').attr('alt');

    $('.modal-title').text(imgAlt);
}
      });
```

I want to add an href link in the photo, when the photo gets bigger.What should I do?

Comment: Please simplify your problem by providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please check this link:-http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `<a href=""></a>`, while you are assigning the `galleryItem`.

Like:

```
var galleryItem = $('<div class="item"><a href="your-link">'+ img +'</a></div>');
```

To add different-different links to each `<a>` use an extra attribute 'data-link' in your link,

```
<a href="#galleryImg1" class="link-gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery" data-link="your-link-1">
```

And in JS, create a variable and get that link via `.attr()` function & append this into your link like,

```
// Get the link from data attribute 'data-link'
var imgLink = $(this).attr('data-link');

// Append the link into the 'galleryItem'
var galleryItem = $('<div class="item"><a href="' + imgLink + '">'+ img +'</a></div>');
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.link-gallery').click(function(){
       var galleryId = $(this).attr('data-target');
       var currentLinkIndex = $(this).index('a[data-target="'+ galleryId +'"]');
       var imgLink = $(this).attr('data-link');

       createGallery(galleryId, currentLinkIndex, imgLink);
       createPagination(galleryId, currentLinkIndex);

       $(galleryId).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (){
           destroyGallry(galleryId);
           destroyPagination(galleryId);
       });

       $(galleryId +' .carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (){
           var currentSlide = $(galleryId +' .carousel .item.active');
           var currentSlideIndex = currentSlide.index(galleryId +' .carousel .item');

           setTitle(galleryId, currentSlideIndex);
           setPagination(++currentSlideIndex, true);
       })
   });

   function createGallery(galleryId, currentSlideIndex, imgLink){
       var galleryBox = $(galleryId + ' .carousel-inner');

       $('a[data-target="'+ galleryId +'"]').each(function(){
           var img = $(this).html();
           var galleryItem = $('<div class="item"><a href="' + imgLink + '">'+ img +'</a></div>');

           galleryItem.appendTo(galleryBox);
       });

       galleryBox.children('.item').eq(currentSlideIndex).addClass('active');
       setTitle(galleryId, currentSlideIndex);
   }

   function destroyGallry(galleryId){
       $(galleryId + ' .carousel-inner').html("");
   }

   function createPagination(galleryId, currentSlideIndex){
       var pagination = $(galleryId + ' .pagination');
       var carouselId = $(galleryId).find('.carousel').attr('id');
       var prevLink = $('<li><a href="#'+ carouselId +'" data-slide="prev">«</a></li>');
       var nextLink = $('<li><a href="#'+ carouselId +'" data-slide="next">»</a></li>');

       prevLink.appendTo(pagination);
       nextLink.appendTo(pagination);

       $('a[data-target="'+ galleryId +'"]').each(function(){
           var linkIndex = $(this).index('a[data-target="'+ galleryId +'"]');
           var paginationLink = $('<li><a data-target="#carouselGallery" data-slide-to="'+ linkIndex +'">'+ (linkIndex+1) +'</a></li>');

           paginationLink.insertBefore('.pagination li:last-child');
       });

       setPagination(++currentSlideIndex);
   }

   function setPagination(currentSlideIndex, reset = false){
       if (reset){
           $('.pagination li').removeClass('active');
       }

       $('.pagination li').eq(currentSlideIndex).addClass('active');
   }

   function destroyPagination(galleryId){
       $(galleryId + ' .pagination').html("");
   }

   function setTitle(galleryId, currentSlideIndex){
       var imgAlt = $(galleryId + ' .item').eq(currentSlideIndex).find('img').attr('alt');

       $('.modal-title').text(imgAlt);
   }
         });
```

```css
.gallery{
margin-top: 100px;
     }
  .gallery-item{
   margin-bottom: 30px;
     }
    .modal-footer{
     text-align: center;
   }
    .pagination{
    margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="gallery">
       <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 gallery-item">
                <a href="#galleryImg1" class="link-gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery" data-link="your-link-1">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive img-gallery" alt="Projekti i pare">
                </a>
            </div> <!-- /.col -->

            <div class="col-xs-3 gallery-item">
                <a href="#galleryImg1" class="link-gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery" data-link="your-link-2">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive img-gallery" alt="Projekti i dyte">
                </a>
            </div> <!-- /.col -->

            <div class="col-xs-3 gallery-item">
                <a href="#galleryImg1" class="link-gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery" data-link="your-link-3">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive img-gallery" alt="Projekti i trete">
                </a>
            </div> <!-- /.col -->

            <div class="col-xs-3 gallery-item">
                <a href="#galleryImg1" class="link-gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery" data-link="your-link-4">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive img-gallery" alt="Projekti i katert">
                </a>
            </div> <!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-xs-3 gallery-item">
                <a href="#galleryImg1" class="link-gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery" data-link="your-link-5">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive img-gallery" alt="Projekti i peste">
                </a>
            </div> <!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-xs-3 gallery-item">
                <a href="#galleryImg1" class="link-gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery" data-link="your-link-6">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive img-gallery" alt="Projekti i gjashte">
                </a>
            </div> <!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-xs-3 gallery-item">
                <a href="#galleryImg1" class="link-gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGallery" data-link="your-link-7">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-responsive img-gallery" alt="Projekti i shtate">
                </a>
                   </div> <!-- /.col -->
              </div> <!--/.row  -->
            </div> <!-- /.container -->
        </div> <!-- /.gallery -->

       <div class="modal fade" id="modalGallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalGalleryLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalGalleryLabel">Gallery</h4>
            </div> <!-- /.modal-header -->

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="carouselGallery" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                    </div> <!-- /.carousel-inner -->
                </div> <!-- /.carousel -->
            </div> <!-- /.modal-body -->

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <ul class="pagination">
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- /.modal-footer -->
        </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div> <!-- /.modal -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you a lot. But what if I want to add different links on photos?Like, one photo one link?

Comment: Dude, you are amazing. Thanks a lot. You literally saved me.

Comment: @Wavelet Its my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Please replace one line in javascript

```js
var galleryItem = $('<div class="item"><a href="http://google.com">'+ img +'</a></div>');
```

hope you will get.

and yes if you want to replace
http://google.com to another one as you want ok.